# Lacking boolean option

Tags: python, modifiers, interface

In the documentation the boolean modifier has some option that I don't have (top pic is documentation and botom is my Blender v2.90.1). I would actually like the option. Are they still there? Maybe through python?

[image]

[image]

Comment: Those options wre only introduced in 2.91 and above.

Comment: Ahh. Just missed them, then. Thanks!

Comment: Is there any further documentation, videos, math etc. which describes the algorithm and the the different settings?

Comment: This thread on devtalk should suit your need https://devtalk.blender.org/t/boolean-improvements/6200

Comment: [Reference release notes](https://wiki.blender.org/wiki/Reference/Release_Notes/2.91/Modeling) might help.